# Running Unix Binaries in Android NDK

Tags: android, linux, unix, android-ndk

is it (theoretically) possible to run any Unix binary from the Android NDK? I have the following binaries available:

```
.rpm, Redhat / CentOS 5.8 i386 RPM
.rpm, Redhat / CentOS 5.8 x86_64 RPM
.tar.gz, Solaris Sparc 2.10
.tar.gz, Cygwin
.tar.gz, MinGW
```

There is also a .tar.gz available that can be installed from Unix Source. The application has command line tools available that I hope to exploit with the NDK. For example:

```
convert image.jpg image.png
```

While I am just starting to run through NDK examples and tutorials, I wanted to see if what I am trying to achieve is possible.

I'm not sure if the above information is enough to tell but, please let me know if there is any more information that I can provide.

Comment: Binaries for x86? No. The vast majority of Android devices is ARM.

Comment: You *might* have some luck with *nix binaries in ELF format that were compiled for ARM CPUs. Those exist (e. g Debian). But no guarantees - Android is not POSIX compliant.

Comment: Thanks Seva, I'll explore that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is its very own architecture, so the files targeted for architectures like i386, x86_64, Solaris, etc. won't work there.  It should be possible to use the NDK to convert a Unix Source bundle into binaries which will work on Android devices.  But how easy or difficult that would be depends on what other libraries or possibly OS features the source itself depends on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to see if I can use the NDK to convert the Unix Source bundle into binaries.

Comment: Such a porting process usually ends up requiring finding or porting versions of typical unix libraries that do not ship with Android by default.  But there are some ways to run an entire Debian ARM linux on a rooted Android device.

Comment: Note also Android uses Bionic libc, not glibc.